# Tracking points move when reopening file

Tags: tracking, movie-clip-editor

I tracked several points on a video and ensured they stayed fixed on the features which I wanted tracked. After saving and reopening the project the markers jump around and are often tens of pixels away from the tracked feature.

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

I'm using Blender 2.79 and the video is MP4 (H.264)

Comment: Has the original video file been altered in any way?

Comment: @cegaton The original video has not been changed in any way.

Comment: Can you upload the blend file and the video file?